# Sharepoint Hosted APPS storage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app

where share point hosted apps will be stored? and is there any difference between APPWEB and HOSTWEB?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint hosted apps are stored in the same site collection as the host web and facilitated by the App Management Service Application. The **host web** is the SharePoint site in which the app in question will be displayed or installed on. The **app web** is a small web instance that is created whenever the installation of an app occurs. Each app has it's own app web and is logically unrelated to the host web.

The host web will have a normal URL like http://sharepoint.domain.com

The app web will have a generated url like: http://app-2b9ff0d7b408ce.appdomain.com

Check out this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/host-webs-add-in-webs-and-sharepoint-components-in-sharepoint

Comment: I have 1 more question. I have server farm or multiple server farms how to change administrative settings globally in SP 2013?

Comment: If you have a different question, please open a new question and it will get the attention you are looking for. Answering unrelated question in comments is out of scope.